# Why build action doesn't work in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I work with project written in C#, I use Visual Studio 2019. There are `.aspx` views in the project. I need to exclude them from build but they should stay in the solution since some tests are linked to them. I use `build action: none`, according to official documentation that means: `The file isn't part of the build in any way.`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2022 . But after the build, when i navigate in browser to these pages - browser starts to download them, which means that they were included into build.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How to exclude these files from the build?

Comment: " but after the build they are still in the project" - what you expect to happen? Where else the files should go from your point of view? Consider showing [mre] as text - list of files in a minimal solution and expected/desired directory structure (again as text).

Comment: Did you meant to say they have been copied to the "output directory" unexpectedly? Surely if the file is part of the project it will stay part of the project on build.

Comment: maybe you mean 'exclude the file from project'?

Comment: I mean, if i use 'Build action: none:" i'm waitng that after the build, when i navigate to this page i will see `404 Not found` or something like this.

@urlreader
@AlexeiLevenkov 
@Ralf

Comment: Try to delete the output directory in Windows Explorer; maybe there are remnants of a previous build there.

Comment: Build action you set is only a hint to the build engine that this file might be treated in a certain way. However, the actual handling is defined in the `targets` files from Microsoft. You can enable MSBuild bin log to learn more, but like the other comment said excluding such files from the project is likely to be the only option for you.

Comment: @LexLi the "content" on ASPX files is important for published version of the project as those with "none" will not be part of the output, it is not "just a hint" for these files.

Comment: As lex li said, excluding such files from the project is likely to be the only option for you. Have you made any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The ASPX files are compiled at run-time from the original location in the source code for local debug/run scenarios (there are no copies for those). From developer's point of view these files already have "Build:none" for *local debugging* purpose. Changing action to "none" does not in any way impact the original content/location of the file so it will still be located at the same place at the run-time on dev box and render at run-time as if it still built.

Where you'll see an impact of "Build:none" is "published" version of the site - with "none" files will not show up in published version and hence will not work from "published" version.